# Как указать URL WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Запущено веб приложение на ASP.net, рядом с ним лежит сервис (*.svc), сейчас используется такой метод для их связи (WEb.config):

```
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost/GiService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
contract="RespService.IProcess"/>
</client>
```

Проблема данного метода что он привязан к конкретному УРЛ, как избежать этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Относительный путь возможен только если укажете базовый адрес (service/host/baseAdresses), ну а при развертывании так или иначе править конфиг.

И в Вашем случае на самом деле еще не проблема, а счастье, что сервис рядом лежит) в противном случае при вызове из аякса, например, начинается веселье :-)